# sql backup restore converts createdAt to local TZ

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, timestamp

I have a remote MySQL DB in the cloud on JAWSDB.

I have `createdAt` and `updatedAt` timestamps for records that are in UTC TZ.

I'll backup these DBs using `mysqldump -h HOST -u USER -p > backup.sql`. I then restore these to a local MySQL Server using
`mysql -u USERNAME -p DB_NAME < backup.sql`

However, upon inspecting the new local backup...I notice that the `createdAt` timestamps are for my local TZ (EST and so currently 5hrs before the UTC version that are actually in JAWSDB). The `updatedAt` timestamps are still in `UTC` though.

Here's how I created those timestamp fields btw.

```
 `createdAt` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updatedAt` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

So it seems like the restore of the dump is converting from UTC to EST just for the `createdAt` field. Could this be due to an engine or mysql version mismatch between JawsDB and my local server?

Any insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
> storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
> (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default,
> the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The
> time zone can be set on a per-connection basis. As long as the time
> zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store.
> If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and
> retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value
> you stored. This occurs because the same time zone was not used for
> conversion in both directions. The current time zone is available as
> the value of the time_zone system variable. For more information, see
> Section 5.1.15, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”.